# ODE - Solving Parameter Dependent on Variable [Matlab]

Tags: matlab, parameter-passing, ode

Lets say I have a function file of the ODE that goes like this

```
function xprime = RabbitTemp(t,X) 

% Model of Rabbit Population
% where,
%       Xo = Initial Population of Rabbits
%       X(1) = Population density of Rabbit
%       X(2) = Temperature T (that varies with time) 
%       a = test parameter

%%% ODE
a  = 10;


dx(1) = (X(1))*(1 - a*X(1) - 3*(X(2))));
dx(2) = sin(t);
%%%%%%%

xprime = [dx(1) dx(2)]';

end
```

But what if I would like parameter **a** to vary as temperature **X(2)** varies, as the ODE solver calculates.

I understand I would first have to create some data between **a** and **X(2)** and interpolate it. But after that I'm not very sure what's next. Could any one point me in the right direction?

Or is there any other way?

Comment: May I add two more cents? 1. You should preallocate `dx` as the first thing in `xprime` and then you can simply return dx instead of copying to `xprime`. No need for two different variables which are the same. 2. Consider defining index variables if your code gets any larger, like `ind.pop_density = 1` and `ind.temp=2`. It will help you in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the function of a, `a=f(T)`. If you can take the derivative of `f(T)` I suggest you include `a` as another state, for instance `X(3)` and then you can access it from the `X` argument in `xprime` easily, plus it will help Matlab determine the proper step size during integration:

```
function xprime = RabbitTemp(t,X) 

% Model of Rabbit Population
% where,
%       Xo = Initial Population of Rabbits
%       X(1) = Population density of Rabbit
%       X(2) = Temperature T (that varies with time) 
%       X(3) = test parameter

%%% ODE
a  = 10;
Yo = 0.4; %Just some Constant

dx(1) = (X(1))*(1 - X(1)^(a) - Yo*(X(2))));
dx(2) = sin(t);
dx(3) = .... 
%%%%%%%

xprime = [dx(1) dx(2) dx(3)]';

end
```

Second method is to create a function(-handle) for `a=f(T)` and call it from within `xprime`:

```
function xprime = RabbitTemp(t,X) 

% Model of Rabbit Population
% where,
%       Xo = Initial Population of Rabbits
%       X(1) = Population density of Rabbit
%       X(2) = Temperature T (that varies with time) 
%       a = test parameter

%%% ODE
a  = f_a(t,X);
Yo = 0.4; %Just some Constant

dx(1) = (X(1))*(1 - X(1)^(a) - Yo*(X(2))));
dx(2) = sin(t);
%%%%%%%

xprime = [dx(1) dx(2)]';

end

function a = f_a(t,X)
  return 10;  % You might want to change this. 
end
```

If possible go with the first variant which is creating another state for `a`.

Comment: thanks for your input. Unfortunately I do not know the actual relation between **a** and **T**.All I have is a set of data (although I could try fitting that data..!), that is why I was thinking about using interp1 to generate more data points, and try and feed it into the solver correspondingly. Hmm!

Comment: In that case I would definitely create a mesh with interpolations beforehand or, like you said, try and fit a curve or something similar. The latter would even result in a differentiable function so I'd try that first :)